# Syntax highlighting conflicts with flymake errline color in emacs?

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, flymake

I'm using flymake with jshint to highlight javascript problems in emacs24. My custom.el has

```
(custom-set-faces '('(flymake-errline ((((class color)) (:background "Red" :foreground "Black")))))
```

This sets the background color to red for code that jshint complains about, and, because some colors are hard to read against a red background, sets the foreground color to black.

The problem is that if the highlighted code has syntax highlighting, the syntax highlighting color overrides my `:foreground "Black"`, and I still wind up not being able to read the highlighted code.

Aside from picking different colors, what are people doing to avoid this problem?

Update: Strangely, some colors **are** overridden by my `:foreground "Black"`.

Answer (score 2):

'cat' this to your emacs config file:

`(custom-set-faces
  '(flymake-errline ((((class color)) (:background "Gray30"))))
  '(flymake-warnline ((((class color)) (:background "Gray20")))))`